# How do I get the type="text" that is disabled to enable when the user deletes what they typed?

Tags: javascript, html

this is what i have, the disableBox() functions disable the textboxes not being used when something is typed. How do i get it to enable the disabled textbox when the user deletes what they typed?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    celsius:
    <input type="text" id="fahrenheit" onkeypress="disableBox()" 
    onkeydown="enableBox()"> 
    <br>
    fahrenheit:
    <input type="text" id="celsius" onkeypress="disableBox2()" 
    onkeydown="enableBox()">
    <br>
    <script>
    var toFahrenheit = document.getElementById("celsius").value;
    var toCelsius  = document.getElementById("fahrenheit").value;
    function disableBox() {    
       if (toFahrenheit = !null ) {
          document.getElementById("fahrenheit").disabled = false;
          document.getElementById("celsius").disabled = true;
       }
    }
    function disableBox2() {
       if (toCelsius = !null) {
          document.getElementById("celsius").disabled = false;
          document.getElementById("fahrenheit").disabled = true;
        } 
    }
    function enableBox() {
      if (toFahrenheit = null ) {
          document.getElementById("fahrenheit").disabled = false;
          document.getElementById("celsius").disabled = false;
       }
      if (toCelsius = null ) {
          document.getElementById("fahrenheit").disabled = false;
          document.getElementById("celsius").disabled = false;
       }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: So if they type into *fahrenheit*, disable *celsius* and if they delete the entry, enable *celsius* again? And *vice versa* if they enter something into *celsius*?

Comment: Please be exact in your question. I do not understand your problem because of a lack of information.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably better off using the keyup event and deciding whether to enable or disable the other input(s) based on its value, e.g.

```js
function disableBox(el) {

  // If value is not empty, disable all inputs except el
  if (el.value != '') {
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input'), function(input) {
      input.disabled = !(input == el);
    });
  
  // Otherwise enable them all
  } else {
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input'), function(input) {
      input.disabled = false;
    });
  }
}
```

```html
celsius:
 <input type="text" id="fahrenheit" onkeyup="disableBox(this)"> 
<br>
fahrenheit:
 <input type="text" id="celsius" onkeyup="disableBox(this)">
```

Of course this will not respond to values cut or pasted using menus or text dragged into or out of the input.

Rather than disabling the other input, why not just make it read only and set the value to the converted temperature?